# Xamarin forms: Camera and gallery are not working in android, showing permission exception

Tags: xamarin.forms, permissions, camera, gallery, media

Getting the following exception when loading the camera and gallery in my project.

**Camera**

> Exception:>Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaPermissionException: Camera permission(s) are required.
>     at Plugin.Media.MediaImplementation+d__17.MoveNext () [0x0009

**Gallery**

> Does not have storage permission granted, requesting.01-02 15:16:08.566 I/mono-stdout(12958): Does not have storage permission granted, requesting.
>   Storage permission Denied.
>   01-02 15:16:08.567 I/mono-stdout(12958): Storage permission Denied.[0:] Exception:>Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaPermissionException: Storage permission(s) are required.
>     at Plugin.Media.MediaImplementation+d__16.MoveNext () [0x00091] in <5939e997f291496f805023da28f3a447>:0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

**I have added all the permissions in my manifest file.**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Added following codes in mainactivity:**

```
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera", Required = false)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera.autofocus", Required = false)]

public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
 {
     PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
 }
```

**Provider details in manifest file:**

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="{packagename}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

**file_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
    <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
</paths>
```

**Camera and Gallery codes:**

```
 public async void OpenMygallery()
    {
        try
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
            {
                ShowAlert("No photos available.");
                return;
            }

            _mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

            if (_mediaFile == null)
                return;

            tweetPicture.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                return _mediaFile.GetStream();
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>" + ex);
        }
    }

public async void OpenMyCamera()
    {
        try
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                ShowAlert("No camera available.");
                return;
            }

            _mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                Directory = "Sample",
                Name = "test.jpg",
                AllowCropping = true
            });

            if (_mediaFile == null)
                return;

            tweetPicture.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                return _mediaFile.GetStreamWithImageRotatedForExternalStorage();
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>" + ex);
        }
    }
```

**Bug Information:**

Version Number of Plugin: 4.0.1.5

Device Tested On: Redmi Note 5 Pro

Version of VS: 15.9.3

Version of Xamarin: 3.4.0.1008975

**Anybody please suggest a solution for this?**

Comment: The user needs to actively give permission for the app to access those features. Have you tried adding permission checks?

Comment: @Tom No, I don't try like that, how to do that?

Comment: Have a look at [James Montemagno's Permissions Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin) about asking for permissions.

Comment: @Tom I will try this and update you soon

Comment: @Tom Please post it as your answer, it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the permissions in the manifest/info.plist files is the first step, but the user needs to also grant those permissions.

You can always add a permission check to make sure that the user has indeed allowed the app to access camera/location/photos/whatever.

Have a look at [James Montemagno's Permissions Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin) about permissions checks and requests.